# Which day of the week again?

Tags: riddle

Today is not Monday, neither it is the day between yesterday and Tuesday. What day is today? That is all information you need.

Comment: Being "the day between yesterday and Tuesday" is exactly equivalent to being Monday. So it could be any day of the week other than Monday. Agreed, this is too broad.

Comment: To be fair, @randal'thor, the puzzle states "neither", which suggests that the day between yesterday and Tuesday is not Monday. And as stated in a few answers now, there is a logical explanation :)

Comment: You could also just say that "Today is not the day between yesterday and Tuesday" and it would still be unique. Today couldn't be Monday, because then it would be the day between Tuesday and yesterday (Sunday).

Comment: "Neither" isn't strictly exclusive though, so that adds a certain amount of flexibility to any answer. Also, "between yesterday and Tuesday" is a non-standard usage if today is not Monday, to the extent that it is arguably not correct English for the meaning intended. Taken together those objections pose problems (I should add that "riddles" seem to be popular when there is more than one correct answer, but only one naively so).

Comment: I think you can now accept Jeff's answer.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> The words "the day" in "the day between yesterday and Tuesday" implies that there is one and only one day between yesterday and Tuesday. The only days that are exactly two days in either direction from Tuesday are Sunday or Thursday. That means that yesterday was either Sunday or Thursday. Since today is not Monday, yesterday was not Sunday, and so yesterday was Thursday, which means today is FRIDAY.

Answer (score 8):

Today is

> Friday

Today is not Monday, neither it is the day between yesterday and Tuesday.

> Since **day between yesterday and Tuesday** is not Monday, **yesterday** must be Thursday so today is Friday.

Comment: Just too slow... :)

Answer (score 3):

> Answer: Today is Friday.

Explanation

> There are only two possible orders for yesterday, "the day between yesterday and Tuesday", and Tuesday.
> If Monday was "the day between yesterday and Tuesday", the days would be Yesterday, "the day between yesterday and Tuesday", and Tuesday, if the days are in chronological order.   So Sunday would be yesterday, today and also "the day between yesterday and Tuesday" would be Monday, and then would come Tuesday. 
> Since today is not Monday and also not "the day between yesterday and Tuesday", today can't be Monday. Therefore the days involved must be in reverse chronological order in "the day between yesterday and Tuesday".
> First comes Tuesday, then "the day between yesterday and Tuesday", and then comes yesterday.
> So "the day between yesterday and Tuesday" should be Wednesday, yesterday should be Thursday, and today should be Friday.
> Answer: Friday.

Comment: Oh hey, welcome to Puzzling! You can improve your answe by adding spoilertags; these are normally expected on answers to challenge questions here, so that people don't see the solution accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

> It's Tuesday because Tuesday can never be between yesterday and Tuesday. And of course Tuesday is not Monday.

Explanation

> Every other day will fall between yesterday and Tuesday. For e.g., Wednesday is between yesterday and Tuesday(next Tuesday).

Comment: apparently that's not the answer, but please use the spoiler thingy in your answer to hide it

Comment: Good try but as Jeff pointed the words "the day" in "the day between yesterday and Tuesday" implies that there is one and only one day between yesterday and Tuesday.Thanks for trying.